# What development tools can build 64 bit programs for Windows x64 and/or Mac?

Tags: ide, 64-bit

Delphi does not yet support building 64-bit applications. What common tools are there for building native 64 bit programs, especially with an IDE? For instance, I believe that Visual Studio supports this. Anything else?

Comment: javac? :-) Or perhaps that's cheating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delphi XE2, with FireMonkey, now supports Windows x64 and the Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, Xcode builds 64-bit apps.  Bear in mind that you must use the Cocoa UI APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2005, Visual Studio 2008, Free Pascal x64.